# Capitalizing issue in the header pages

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, capitalization, header

In the header's "review queues" drop-down menu, in the link text of "all queues" and "tools", the first character is a capital letter:

[image: All queues]

But in the "achievements" drop down menu, the link text of "privileges" and "badges" is a small letter:

[image: privileges]

For consistency, the links should either have small characters or be capitalized everywhere in the header menus.

Comment: The [inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM5IG.png) and [hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MyiI.png) suffer from this inconsistency as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure capitalizating the first letter is correct per [the Stacks guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing). I think those non-capitalized parts of the page just haven't been updated to bring them in line with the Stacks guidelines.